# Having a subview that shows a portion of an image contained in its superview

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to create a 'monocle' view of sorts that you can move around and scale that will show a section of a larger image (section size is defined by the monocle's bounds). The larger image should not show beyond the bounds the monocle.

Right now I have a `UIImageView` (called lensImage) which is a subview of a `UIView` named lens.

I was attempting to use a 2D `CGAffineTransform` to show the relevant section of an image based off of the monocle's position, but that would snap the image to odd positions.

Any tips on what I need to work with?

Here is a diagram explaining the desired setup:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'it would snap the image to odd positions'?  What you've described sounds like a great way to do this, to me, so I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong so we can help you :)

Comment: Basically, on moving the monocle, I would use a CGAffineTransformTranslate on the layer of either the monocle or superview (can't remember which) using the coordinates of the touch involved. When I would move the monocle, however, the image would either snap out of view (exposing just the background color), or an erroneous location.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. My initial thought is that this might be a question of local v global coordinates--ie. if the touch is being registered for the entire screen, maybe those coordinates haven't been localized to the view you're moving, causing incorrect positioning.  Can you throw up some code?  I'd like to take a look at what you were doing and try to spot the error.

Comment: I figured out the moving around aspect of the problem. I didn't even use a CGAffineTransform. I modified the position of the `lensImage` subview layer as the touch location changes:

`self.lensImage.layer.position = CGPointMake(((self.superview.frame.size.width/2)+100)-[touch locationInView:self.superview].x,self.superview.frame.size.height/2+60-[touch locationInView:self.superview].y);`

The two integers in this expression are there as a hack, not sure what is causing the offset. All that's left now is pinching to resize the view, which I can do on my own. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!  Would you be so kind as to post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that others who come along in the future with similar problems can be helped?  Thanks!